How to Save User and Fetch Chat According to User ID using infobip service
I’ve successfully implemented Infobip Mobile Messaging for chat in my app, and it’s working perfectly. However, I’m facing an issue where chat messages are displayed according to the device, not the user. Specifically, if a user logs in on one account, chats are shown correctly. But if the user logs out and another user logs in on the same device, the previous chat messages still appear. This means that when the new user opens the chat, they see old messages from the previous account, which is not acceptable.
I need a solution to ensure that chat messages are associated with the current user ID so that each user only sees their own chat history.
From the Infobip Mobile Messaging package I found the  personalization and profiling.. I’m attempting to use the personalize but I’m encountering an error. Here’s the code from my InfobipService class:
class InfobipService {
  static bool isNotificationTap = false;
  static String? eventName;
  static String registrationId = "";

  static String apiKey = '***';

  static void initializeInfobip() async {
    try {
      await InfobipMobilemessaging.init(mmconfiguration.Configuration(
          applicationCode: dotenv.env['infobipAppCode'] ?? '',
          inAppChatEnabled: true,
          fullFeaturedInAppsEnabled: false,
          inAppChatCustomization: mmconfiguration.InAppChatCustomization(
              toolbarTintColor: '0xFFFFFFFF'),
          defaultMessageStorage: true,
          privacySettings: mmconfiguration.PrivacySettings(
            userDataPersistingDisabled: false,
            carrierInfoSendingDisabled: false,
            systemInfoSendingDisabled: false,
          ),
          iosSettings: IOSSettings(
              notificationTypes: ['alert', 'badge', 'sound'], logging: true)));
      
      await InfobipMobilemessaging.registerForRemoteNotifications();
      
      InfobipMobilemessaging.on(
        LibraryEvent.registrationUpdated,
        (String token) {
          registrationId = token;
          log('Callback. TOKEN_RECEIVED event: ${token}');
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error initializing Infobip Mobile Messaging: $e');
    }
  }

  // Call this when user logs in or registers
  static Future<void> personalize(String uniquePersonId) async {
    try {
       var user = UserIdentity(
        externalUserId: uniquePersonId);

     var personalizeContext = PersonalizeContext(
        userIdentity: user, userAttributes: null, forceDepersonalize: true);
      await InfobipMobilemessaging.personalize(personalizeContext);
      log('Personalized with user ID: $uniquePersonId');
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error personalizing: $e');
    }
  }

calling this method after log in
void personalizeUser(String uniquePersonId) async {
  await InfobipService.personalize(uniquePersonId);
  }

Error:
**Error personalizing: PlatformException(-1, Unknown error, SERVER_ERROR, -1, Unknown error, null)**

on more thing i would like to ask, when personalizeUser methdod calls on terminal it prints this log
Request(httpMethod=POST, uri=https://mobile.infobip.com/mobile/1/appinstance/4c865cac-9070-47b7-bd3e-b66782e52ddf/personalize, apiKey=***, credentials=null, headers={applicationcode=[***], pushregistrationid=[4c865cac-9070-47b7-bd3e-b66782e52ddf], foreground=[true], sessionId=[4c865cac-9070-47b7-bd3e-b66782e52ddf_1724916404806], installationid=[54f94c15-1322-4fb5-80b9-beecb6a220a3]}, queryParams={forceDepersonalize=[true]}, body={"userIdentity":{"emails":[],"externalUserId":"123","phones":[]}})

in apiKey it is taking application code, isn't it should take apiKey? and i am not using apiKey too. Please help how to fix this issue.
